# Django Select query with specific column

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model called `MessagePerson` which has the fields of details which depict the messages for a particular person, who's details are in `Personal` models.

I even have separate model which has a foreign key reference to `Personal` class.

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    contact =  models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pic = models.FileField(upload_to='image/',blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name    

class MessagePerson(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Personal, related_name='msg')
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mPhone = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    memail = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person.name

class GData(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Personal, related_name='everyperson')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    typeOfProperty = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    typeOfPlace = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person.name
```

Now the thing I require is, I have the `id` of `GData` using which i should save a message for the particular 'MessagePerson`using name of`Personal`

The query I used is :
Views.py

```
def message(request, g_id):
    n = request.POST['bname']
    p = request.POST['bphone']
    e = request.POST['bemail']
    m = request.POST['bmsg']

    mperson = GData.objects.get(id=g_id).values('person')

    msg_job = MessagePerson(person=mperson, mname=n, mPhone=p, memail=e, message=m)
    msg_job.save()
    return render_to_response('ivent.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now the thing is, without any error, it is not even storing the message :(

Please help me to get the result :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thing that stands out is that:

```
mperson = GData.objects.get(id=g_id).values('person')
```

should probably be:

```
mperson = GData.objects.get(id=g_id).person
```

You should also probably rethink your view logic, just looking quickly something like this is slightly better, but can probably be improved:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 

def message(request, g_id):
    mperson = get_objects_or_404(GData, id=g_id).person

    if request.method == 'POST':
        n = request.POST.get('bname')
        p = request.POST.get('bphone')
        e = request.POST.get('bemail')
        m = request.POST.get('bmsg')
        msg_job = MessagePerson(person=mperson, mname=n, mPhone=p, memail=e, message=m)
        msg_job.save()
        return render_to_response('ivent.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return HttpResponse('Not a post request')
```

Comment: DTing, your right - my answer wouldn't have worked - that will teach me for not checking an answer :-)

Comment: @DTing : Ur solution worked when i used it in `python manage.py shell` , but through the website it is not saving the object. :( Should i provide any further details? The site when submits just gives back the same page without even the success notice, which i have created .

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if the instance is saved?

Comment: Also, after your save it seems like you would want to redirect to another view not render_to_response.

Comment: @DTing : I did check the database. I checked them through the admin site of django. If i put the data from `shell` it gets saved. Before this there was another same insert type situation. That works perfectly. But this doesn't. And Yea I am rendering them to same page not redirecting :(