# Model.objects.only("columnname") doesn't work. It shows me everything

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model called Theme. It has a lot of columns, but I need to retrieve only the field called "name", so I did this:

Theme.objects.only("name")

But it doesn't work, it is still retrieving all the columns.

PD: I don't want to use values() because it returns only a python dictionary. I need to return a set of model instances, to access to its attributes and methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Select query with specific column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007298/django-select-query-with-specific-column)

Comment: That question doesn't respond to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `only` or its counterpart `defer` does not prevent accessing the deferred attributes. It only delays retrieval of said attributes until they are accessed. So take the following:

```
for theme in Theme.objects.all():
    print theme.name
    print theme.other_attribute
```

This will execute a single query when the loop starts. Now consider the following:

```
for theme in Theme.objects.only('name'):
    print theme.name
    print theme.other_attribute
```

In this case, the `other_attribute` is not loaded in the initial query at the start of the loop. However, it is added to the model's list of deferred attributes. When you try to access it, another query is executed to retrieve the value of `other_attribute`. In the second case, a total of n+1 queries is executed for n `Theme` objects.

The `only` and `defer` methods should only ever be used in advanced use-cases, after the need for optimization arises, and after proper analysing of your code. Even then, there are often workarounds that work better than deferring fields. Please read the note at the bottom of the `defer` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

Comment: Thanks. That's responds to my question.
Yes, I turned on the SQL Query logs and I noticed that if use only() and then print a defered field, it executes an internal query to the database to retrieve only that specific refered field.

Comment: You think it's normal that selecting a few columns and avoiding `SELECT *` is considered to be an advanced use-case?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a single column, I think what you are looking for is [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) instead of `.only`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use values() because it returns only a python dictionary. I need to return a set of model instances, to access to its attributes and methods.

Comment: Aye, but `.only()` is the compliment of `.defer()`. Either way the returned Model instance will have all the defined columns, but the ORM will not load the deferred columns from the database unless you ask for them.

If what you want is just the value for name, have you tried `Theme.objects.only('name').name`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. it works. But if I do the same with another column it is also printed, example: Theme.objects.only("name").user_id also prints the value

Comment: It prints because the Model instance still has all the columns _defined_, even if retrieval is deferred. If you need a data structure that _can't_ access the other columns, I think your options are using `.values()` or sub-classing your Model and defining only the name field.

Comment: I note that the `ValuesQuerySet` instance returned by `.values()` can still use `.filter()`, `.order_by()`, _etc._